# Angular 9 - Different result when clicking button on desktop vs IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, angular8, angular9

I am creating a test app that shows computer generated images.
I load these via a service that gets them from an api, get each gets a new random one.

Initially the left button is disabled until they user clicks the right button and loads the next images.

If the user is at the end of the image array and they click right it will either load a new images OR if there is images already in a buffer array then it will remove one from the buffer and add to the normal images array, and move up the index and show the image.

The issue is that on desktop everything works fine. No issue.
The problem is when I run the app from an IPhone. When the user clicks the right button, the left button does become enabled which is correct, but the image does not change. If the user clicks right again then the image will change.

For some reason either the logic is changing or something is happening in how IOS handles my code or background loading of images? Perhaps the http observables are handled differently on mobile?

the app is at https://app.imageloadertest.com
Try it on desktop first, then try it on a Iphone.

**left button:**

```
  <button
    nbButton
    status="info"
    class="butt"
    style="margin-right: 10px"
    (click)="goLeft()"
    data-tap-disabled="true"
    disabled="{{ isLeftDisabled }}"
  >
    <nb-icon icon="arrow-back-outline"></nb-icon>
  </button>
```

**right button:**

```
  <button
    nbButton
    status="info"
    class="butt"
    data-tap-disabled="true"
    (click)="goRight()"
    disabled="{{ isRightDisabled }}"
  >
    <nb-icon icon="arrow-forward-outline"></nb-icon>
  </button>
```

**variables:**

```
isImageLoading: Boolean = false;

 

  imageToShow: any;
  imageVisible = false;

  maxLoadedImages = 50;
  images: any[] = [];
  curIndex = 0;
  isLeftDisabled = true;
  isDownloadDisabled = true;
  isRightDisabled = true;

  minBufferImages = 5;
  bufferImages: any[] = [];
```

**ngOnInit**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.faceDataService.getImageData().subscribe(result => {
      this.createImageFromBlob(result);
    });

    this.startBufferingImages(this.minBufferImages);
  }
```

**functions:**

```
  getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(imageUrl, { responseType: "blob" });
  }

  goRight() {
    if (this.images.length - 1 == this.curIndex) {
      if (this.images.length > this.maxLoadedImages) {
        --this.curIndex;
        this.images.shift();
      }

      if (this.bufferImages.length - 1 == 0) {
        this.isRightDisabled = true;
        this.faceDataService.getImageData().subscribe(result => {
          this.imageVisible = false;
          this.createImageFromBlob(result);
          ++this.curIndex;
          this.isLeftDisabled = false;
        });
      } else {
        this.imageVisible = false;
        ++this.curIndex;
        this.isLeftDisabled = false;
        let bufferedImage = this.bufferImages.pop();
        this.images.push(bufferedImage);
        this.imageToShow = bufferedImage;
        this.imageVisible = true;

        if (this.bufferImages.length < this.minBufferImages) {
          this.startBufferingImages(this.minBufferImages);
        }
      }
    } else {
      ++this.curIndex;
      this.imageToShow = this.images[this.curIndex];
      this.isLeftDisabled = false;
    }
  }

  goLeft() {
    --this.curIndex;
    if (this.curIndex <= 0) {
      this.isLeftDisabled = true;
    }
    this.imageToShow = this.images[this.curIndex];
  }

  createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener(
      "load",
      () => {
        this.imageToShow = reader.result;
        this.imageVisible = true;
        this.images.push(reader.result);
        this.isDownloadDisabled = false;
        this.isRightDisabled = false;
      },
      false
    );

    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }

  startBufferingImages(amount: number) {
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
      this.faceDataService.getImageData().subscribe(result => {
        this.createBufferImageFromBlob(result);
      });
    }
  }

  createBufferImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener(
      "load",
      () => {
        this.bufferImages.push(reader.result);
      },
      false
    );

    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }
```

Comment: could it be cause mobile network is slower and your images are big (~1.2mb) so it hasnt populated buffer yet when you click next ?

Comment: I thought of this and made sure the iphone was on wifi and the internet connection is fast 60-100mbps. I also waited some time etc to test this.